# Rails Nested Model Attribute 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' possible bug on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I expect found a bug in rails v2.3.8, but I'm asking here in case I'm just doing something stupid.

I have a 3-deep nested model that describes a shipment (i.e. shipment -> boxes -> line-items in boxes).  The shipment and boxes are created at the same time, but the line-items already exist, from when the order was placed, so line-items just need to be associated with the box they are in.

The create method for `shipment` give me this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find VendorOrderLine with ID=3 for VendorShippingBox with ID=)
```

And shows SQL it tried to execute:

```
SELECT * FROM "vendor_order_lines" WHERE ("vendor_order_lines"."id" IN ('3','4')) AND ("vendor_order_lines".vendor_shipping_box_id = NULL)
```

Notice that `vendor_shipping_box_id` is not in quotes.

If I run this query in the console with:

```
VendorOrderLine.find(:all, :conditions=>["vendor_order_lines.id IN ('3', '4') AND vendor_order_lines.vendor_shipping_box_id IS NULL"])
```

I get the expected result.  Oddly enough, the `update` method works fine

I can post more details if needed, but the rails generated SQL should have `vendor_shipping_box_id` in quotations, and that's what's causing the `ActiveRecord` error, correct?  Or am I missing something?

(note, my models/controllers/views are all setup per Ryan Bates' RailsCasts ep: 196 & 197)

---

UPDATE:  I updated to Rails 3.0, and the create method works as expected.  So this is definitely a bug.  Is it proper to report a bug for previous versions of software?  Where can I find documentation on rails bugs/bug reporting?

Answer (score 0):

I've run across this same issue but not found a fix/work around yet, we can't upgrade to rails 3 or newer versions of rails 2.3 at this time unfortunately.